# PHP não cria arquivo

Tags: php

Bom dia Pessoal,
veja se alguém já viu acontecer algo parecido,tenho um script em php que                   recebe uma solicitação post de um json vindo do android,ate um certo momento esta funcionando legal,percebi que quando o json tem 80 linhas o php consegue gerar um arquivo txt que salvo em uma pasta no servidor.
Esses dias percebi que quando o json ultrapassa as 80 linhas o php não faz nada.
meu servidor aqui e windows server.
eu fiz um teste em duas hospedagem gratuita com o mesmo script e funcionou legal   se problemas.Será que é alguma configuração no servidor ?

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["site"])) {
 $jsonObj = json_decode($_POST["site"]); 
 $json    = json_encode($jsonObj);
 $json = str_replace("},{","},\r\n{",$json);//quebrando em linhas

 $json = str_replace("\u00e3","a",$json);//alterando ã para a 
 $json = str_replace("\u00e1","a",$json);//alterando á para a
 $json = str_replace("\u00f5","o",$json);//alterando õ para o 
 $json = str_replace("\u00f3","o",$json);//alterando ó para o
 $json = str_replace("\u00e7","c",$json);//alterando ç para c
 $json = str_replace("\u00ea","e",$json);//alterando ê para e
 $json = str_replace("\u00f4","o",$json);//alterando ô para o

 $nomeArquivo  = date("d-m-y_H-i-s").".txt";     
 $file = fopen($nomeArquivo,'w');
 fwrite($file,$json);//granvando as linhas do arquivo
 echo 'Arquivo gerado com sucesso';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Coloque o código que recebe esse `JSON`

Comment: na variável `$jsonObj` qual é o valor que tem? coloque um exemplo minimo desse contéudo da variavel, um dica quando for colocar uma pergunta, coloque todo o contéudo relacionado.

Comment: {"gps":[{"_idt2":"0000011156","_latitude2":"-22.692567765033814","_longitude2":"-46.87084518790105","_dataHora2":"23-09-2016 08:17:25"},
{"_idt2":"0000011156","_latitude2":"-22.692615335511125","_longitude2":"-46.87082535684631","_dataHora2":"23-09-2016 08:17:35"}]}

Comment: Você verificou se o JSON está chegando inteiro quando tem muitas linhas  ? Algumas vezes o servidor reinicia a conexão e não da tempo de enviar tudo

Comment: Então Lucas ,como disse,ate 80 linhas ele cria normal,acima disso não.é isso que acho estranho

Comment: Você recebe algum erro no Android  ao enviar ? tá enviando com alguma Lib ?

Comment: Lucas,eu coloquei o mesmo script em outros dois servidores de hospedagem para testar, Hostinger e qlix,nois dois funciona normal

Comment: No android,eu to usando o volley,retorna 'Erro ao enviar',pois fiz um if else no php,quando da certo retorna a ,mensagem  'Arquivo gerado com sucesso'; quem é do echo do php,quando não da certo entra no else e retorna 'Erro ao enviar'.

Comment: Certo, mas ele cai no response normal né ? não no ErrorListener ? Eu tive um problema semelhante quando estava testando com um webservice da Protheus, ao enviar uma foto em base 64 ele me retornava um erro de Socket

Comment: isso,cai no response.O mais estranho que nos outros servidores funciona normal,eu to achando que deve ser alguma configuração do lado do servidor,mais não sei qual.O servidor aqui e Windows server